# Using a function with an unknown argument type?

Tags: c++

I'm making a text based RPG for fun. I'm working on my combat function that will control how combat works etc...

I have an entity class with basic variables that all other "entities" in the game world will have. From there, I have various monster classes such as "rat," "golem," "dragon," etc... These specific enemy classes inherit the variables within the entity class.

The combat function has two arguments, the hero (player) and the enemy the hero will be fighting. The problem is, I don't know what type of class the enemy will be. Sometimes it will be a rat, golem etc...

Each enemy class has its own unique set of abilities. I need to be able to use those abilities to damage the player in the combat function.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: But you do know that the hero will be fighting an entity. Add to the entity class the appropriate methods needed to conduct a fight.

Comment: a problem that could be solved by polymorphism. Did you consider that?

Comment: I'm mostly self taught as a programmer so I had to actually go look into polymorphism for a few minutes. Using polymorphism, I would need to create virtual functions in the entity class and then corresponding functions in the rat, dragon, golem classes that tailor to their specific attacks. However, what if a rat only has 2 attacks while a dragon has 4?

Comment: Add a getNumberOfAttacks function. For class rat it returns 2. For dragon, 4

Answer (score 1):

If you can resolve without separate function, you could use your entity class for attacks.

```
...
virtual void attacked(Player pObject)=0;
...
```

This pure virtual function can be written in parent, so each derivate would have the specific attack method.

Comment: @user4581301 Sorry, I didn't read the comments. I gave you upvote.

Comment: Not ripping on you. I was half-way through posting a nearly identical answer when you posted.

Comment: @user4581301 OK, you know what? Suggest an edit, and mention your name in it.

Comment: Why? Your answer is good the way it is. AT this point OP either understands polymorphism and can implement this or doesn't and needs to do some reading.